# How can I make a custom range input work for touch screens?

Tags: javascript, touch

I have a custom range slider.

The issue I'm running into, however, is that I can't manage to make the sliding of the custom “thumb” (in this case ) work on touch devices.

Here's the project live: https://wagon-city-guides.herokuapp.com/spots/32

If you check it on your mobile (I use an iPhone), you'll still see the border of the original thumb (I left it on purpose for now), which slides and works, but the flame (the custom thumb) doesn’t come along … while it works fine for click devices.

I'm looking for a Vanilla JS solution only.

Here's my code:

```
class RatingSlider {
  constructor() {
    this.ratingSliderForm = document.querySelector(".js-rating-slider-form");
    this.ratingSliderInput = document.querySelector(".js-rating-slider-input");
    this.ratingSliderThumb = document.querySelector(".js-rating-slider-thumb");
    this.ratingSliderValue = document.querySelector(".js-rating-slider-value");
    this.ratingSliderIcon = document.querySelector(".js-rating-slider-icon");
    this.isPressed = false;
    this.moveEvent;
    this.holdEvent;
    this.releaseEvent;
    this.bind();
  }

  handleSliding(event) {
    if (!this.isPressed) {
      return;
    }
    if (
      event.offsetX > 0 &&
      event.offsetX < this.ratingSliderInput.offsetWidth
    ) {
      this.ratingSliderThumb.style.left = `${event.offsetX - 10}px`;
      this.ratingSliderIcon.style.transform = `scale(${1 +
        this.ratingSliderInput.value / 150})`;
      this.ratingSliderValue.innerText = `${this.ratingSliderInput.value}°`;
    }
  }

  setRating() {
    this.ratingSliderThumb.style.left = `${(this.ratingSliderInput.offsetWidth /
      100) *
      this.ratingSliderInput.value -
      10}px`;
    this.ratingSliderIcon.style.transform = `scale(${1 +
      this.ratingSliderInput.value / 150})`;
    this.ratingSliderValue.innerText = `${this.ratingSliderInput.value}°`;
    this.ratingSliderInput.addEventListener(
      `${this.holdEvent}`,
      () => (this.isPressed = true)
    );
    this.ratingSliderInput.addEventListener(`${this.releaseEvent}`, () => {
      this.isPressed = false;
      this.ratingSliderForm.submit();
    });
  }

  setEvents() {
    if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) {
      this.moveEvent = "touchmove";
      this.holdEvent = "touchstart";
      this.releaseEvent = "touchend";
    } else {
      this.moveEvent = "mousemove";
      this.holdEvent = "mousedown";
      this.releaseEvent = "mouseup";
    }
  }

  bind() {
    if (!this.ratingSliderForm) {
      return;
    }
    this.setEvents();
    this.setRating();
    this.ratingSliderInput.addEventListener(`${this.moveEvent}`, event =>
      this.handleSliding(event)
    );
  }
}

export default RatingSlider;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the touch events don't have `offsetX` and `offsetY` properties. Their values are returning `undefined` in mobile devices. So, you need to add those to the event.

Right at the beginning of `handleSliding(event)` method, add this:

```
if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) {
  event = addOffsetsOnTouch(event);
}

function addOffsetsOnTouch(e) {
  let touch = e.touches[0] || event.changedTouches[0];
  let target = document.elementFromPoint(touch.clientX, touch.clientY);
  event.offsetX = touch.clientX - target.getBoundingClientRect().x;
  event.offsetY = touch.clientY - target.getBoundingClientRect().y
  return e;
}
```

Comment: ⭐️Thank you. One note, by the way, I see you use both `e` and `event` in this snippet.

Comment: Yes, It is to differentiate the event inside the `handleSliding (event)` and the parameter in the `addOffsetsOnTouch`.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Azametzin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8598108/azametzin)'s answer I refactored the method that handles the offset for touch and non-touch devices into the following:

```
  handleOffsetOnChange(event) {
    if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) {
      let touch = event.touches[0];
      let target = this.ratingSliderInput;
      event.offsetX = touch.clientX - target.getBoundingClientRect().x;
    }
    if (
      event.offsetX > 0 &&
      event.offsetX < this.ratingSliderInput.offsetWidth
    ) {
      this.ratingSliderThumb.style.left = `${event.offsetX - 10}px`;
    }
  }
```

Here's the entire file:

```
class RatingSlider {
  constructor() {
    this.ratingSliderForm = document.querySelector(".js-rating-slider-form");
    this.ratingSliderInput = document.querySelector(".js-rating-slider-input");
    this.ratingSliderThumb = document.querySelector(".js-rating-slider-thumb");
    this.ratingSliderValue = document.querySelector(".js-rating-slider-value");
    this.ratingSliderIcon = document.querySelector(".js-rating-slider-icon");
    this.isPressed = false;
    this.setEvents();
    this.setPositionThumb();
    this.setThumbStyle();
    this.bind();
  }
  setEvents() {
    this.moveEvent;
    this.startEvent;
    this.endEvent;
    if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) {
      this.moveEvent = "touchmove";
      this.startEvent = "touchstart";
      this.endEvent = "touchend";
    } else {
      this.moveEvent = "mousemove";
      this.startEvent = "mousedown";
      this.endEvent = "mouseup";
    }
  }

  setThumbStyle() {
    this.ratingSliderIcon.style.transform = `scale(${1 +
      this.ratingSliderInput.value / 150})`;
    this.ratingSliderValue.innerText = `${this.ratingSliderInput.value}°`;
  }

  setPositionThumb() {
    this.ratingSliderThumb.style.left = `${(this.ratingSliderInput.offsetWidth /
      100) *
      this.ratingSliderInput.value -
      10}px`;
  }

  handleOffsetOnChange(event) {
    if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) {
      let touch = event.touches[0];
      let target = this.ratingSliderInput;
      event.offsetX = touch.clientX - target.getBoundingClientRect().x;
    }
    if (
      event.offsetX > 0 &&
      event.offsetX < this.ratingSliderInput.offsetWidth
    ) {
      this.ratingSliderThumb.style.left = `${event.offsetX - 10}px`;
    }
  }

  bind() {
    if (!this.ratingSliderForm) {
      return;
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => this.setPositionThumb());

    this.ratingSliderInput.addEventListener(
      this.startEvent,
      () => (this.isPressed = true)
    );

    this.ratingSliderInput.addEventListener(this.endEvent, () => {
      this.isPressed = false;
      this.ratingSliderForm.submit();
    });

    this.ratingSliderInput.addEventListener(this.moveEvent, (event) => {
      if (!this.isPressed) {
        return;
      }
      this.handleOffsetOnChange(event);
      this.setThumbStyle();
    });
  }
}

export default RatingSlider;
```